# building for UIKitForMac, but linking in .tbd built for macOS

Tags: xcode11, uikitformac

I'm trying to compile my iOS app to work on macOS and after checking the Mac checkbox, I'm getting this error on compile:

> d: building for UIKitForMac, but linking in .tbd built for macOS, file '/Users/jan/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//GLKit.framework/GLKit.tbd' for architecture x86_64

Any idea what it means and how to fix it?

Comment: Is GLKit supported on the Mac for Catalyst? With Apple moving from OpenGL ES to Metal, GLKit may not be available for Mac.

Comment: I know this kind of error is triggered when the app tries to include a framework that is not supported by that specific target or architecture but according to Apple, it **should** be available for both MacOSX and UIKitForMac: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/glkit.

Comment: We're having the same issue, did you find a solution? Or have you submitted a bug report to Apple?

Comment: In my case, I believe it's a problem that the Google Maps team need to solve on their side, as I only get this problem when I use their library

Answer (score 1):

Though I've not had this particular error I have had similar ones when trying to port from iPad to UIKitForMac. UIKitForMac appears to be the iOS SDK built for x86_64 when you're linking with frameworks. As a result it shouldn't be trying to pull the x86_64 files from the macOS SDK.

I'd be tempted to check over your 'architectures' and 'valid architectures' settings in Xcode to make sure that any settings you have are deleted and switched back to the standard ones.

[Remove architectures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oyaw.png)